# Tkinter Button unable to find callback command

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on a program that reads and parses a config file for an embedded hardware system I'm working on. I'm trying to use tkinter and python to make a simple GUI for reading and writing this file. I have the file IO and parsing mostly working, but I'm having trouble getting all the parts integrated with the GUI. I want to read the information off of the device and then populate the entry fields with the relevant info. The problem that I'm having is I keep getting the error

```
"in initUI
opnBut = Button(butFrm, text="Open", command=openCfg)
NameError: name 'openCfg' is not defined"
```

I can get it to find the function if I put it outside the Application class but then I can't figure out how to reference the fields inside the window I've made to update them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code segment is included below.

```
class Application(Frame):
    def openCfg():
    name = getNameFromFile()
    nameEntry.insert(0, name)



    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Config Reader")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        nameFrm = Frame(self)
        nameFrm.pack(fill=X)

        nameLbl = Label(nameFrm, text="Device Name",width=20)
        nameLbl.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5, pady=5)
        nameEntry = Entry(nameFrm)
        nameEntry.pack(fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)

        butFrm = Frame(self)
        butFrm.pack(fill=X)
        opnBut = Button(butFrm, text="Open Cfg", command=openCfg)
        opnBut.pack(fill=X, padx=5,pady=5)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")

app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you meant `self.openCfg`, but (as Andrew said) your code would throw an IndentationError if this is really it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

items which are defined in the class namespace are bound to the class.  In this case, you have a couple options...

One option is that you could make it a `staticmethod`:

```
class Application(Frame):
    @staticmethod
    def openCfg():
        name = getNameFromFile()
        nameEntry.insert(0, name)
```

And then bind the button as:

```
opnBut = Button(butFrm, text="Open Cfg", command=self.openCfg)
```

However, staticmethods are rarely necessary.  In this case, I might just move the definition of `openCfg` out of the class and keep everything else as it is:

```
def openCfg():
    name = getNameFromFile()
    nameEntry.insert(0, name)

class Application(Frame):
    ...
```

---

On a second look, this will probably still bring up a `NameError` for `nameEntry`.  You'll probably want a first-class method:

```
class Application(Frame):
    def openCfg(self):
        name = getNameFromFile()
        self.nameEntry.insert(0, name)
```

And of course, when you create `nameEntry`, you'll need to make it a member of the Application class.

```
...
self.nameEntry = Entry(nameFrm)
self.nameEntry.pack(fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
...
```